# Using a regular expression to save script src url

Tags: php, regex

```
<script language='javascript' src='http://api.psusedo.com/board@top_<?=$id?>'></script>
```

I try to save the value of script src through regular expression in two.

One tries to save before the _ sign(Ex:http://api.psusedo.com/board@top_ )
and the other one after the _ sign.(Ex: )

```
\_(.*)
```

The string after _ including this regular expression was found.

How do I save a character string around _ and how do I do it?

Comment: What happened to the previous question you asked on this topic? Please don't duplicate questions on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
src\s*=\s*'([^_]*)_([^']*)'\s*>
```

1. in group 1 you get the value before underscore (_) sign
2. in group 2 you get the value after underscore (_) sign

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6fa4tl/1/)

Sample Code:

```
$re = '/src\s*=\s*\'([^_]*)_([^\']*)\'\s*>/';
$str = '<script language=\'javascript\' src=\'http://api.psusedo.com/board@top_<?=$id?>\'></script>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
// Print the entire match result
```

var_dump($matches);